# Recursão infinita em um modelo ManyToMany bidirecional no hibernate

Tags: java, json, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

Eu estou tentando criar uma relação ManyToMany bidirecional no Java, Eu já consigo inserir no banco de dados sem problemas, mas quando eu tento trazer dados dessas tabelas eu caio em uma recursão infinita... eu vi que isso é um erro conhecido do Json no java e tentei implementar as soluções nesse [baeldung tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-bidirectional-relationships-and-infinite-recursion)
 mas nenhuma delas funcionou, talvez eu esteja colocando as anotações no local errado.

***O que eu preciso é encontrar 1 estudante(Student), e todos os cursos(Course) no qual ele se cadastrou. (nesse problema em si, a base de professores(Teacher) não está envolvida) ***

**Database**

[image]

***Models***

***Student***

```
@Component
@Entity
@Table(name="Student")
public class Student {

    @Id
    @Column(name="student_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name="student_name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name="student_address")
    private String address;

    @Column(name="student_email")
    private String email;

    @Column(name="student_username")
    private String username;

    @Column(name="student_password")
    private String password;

    @JsonManagedReference
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="pk.student")
    private Set<StudentCourse> studentCourses;

    public Student() {
        studentCourses = new HashSet<StudentCourse>(0);
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public Set<StudentCourse> getCourses() {
        return studentCourses;
    }

    public void setCourses(Set<StudentCourse> studentCourses) {
        this.studentCourses = studentCourses;
    }


}
```

***Course***

```
@Component
@Entity
@Table(name="Course")
public class Course {

    @Id
    @Column(name="course_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @Column(name="course_name")
    private String name;
    @Column(name="course_schedule")
    private String schedule;    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "teacher_id")
    private Teacher teacher;

    @JsonBackReference
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="pk.course")
    private Set<StudentCourse> studentCourses = new HashSet<StudentCourse>(0);

    public Course() {

    }


    public Teacher getTeacher() {
        return teacher;
    }

    public void setTeacher(Teacher teacher) {
        this.teacher = teacher;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }


    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }


    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getSchedule() {
        return schedule;
    }

    public void setSchedule(String schedule) {
        this.schedule = schedule;
    }

    public Set<StudentCourse> getStudentCourses() {
        return studentCourses;
    }

    public void setStudentCourses(Set<StudentCourse> studentCourses) {
        this.studentCourses = studentCourses;
    }


}
```

***StudentCourse***

```
@Component
@Entity
@Table(name="Student_Course")
@AssociationOverrides({
    @AssociationOverride(name = "pk.student", 
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "student_id")),
    @AssociationOverride(name = "pk.course", 
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "course_id")) })
public class StudentCourse implements java.io.Serializable {

    @EmbeddedId
    private StudentCourseId pk = new StudentCourseId();

    public StudentCourseId getPk() {
        return pk;
    }

    public void setPk(StudentCourseId pk) {
        this.pk = pk;
    }

    @Transient
    public Student getStudent() {
        return getPk().getStudent();
    }

    public void setStudent(Student student) {
        getPk().setStudent(student);
    }

    @Transient
    public Course getCourse() {
        return getPk().getCourse();
    }

    public void setCourse(Course course) {
        getPk().setCourse(course);
    }


}
```

***StudentCourseId***

```
@Embeddable
public class StudentCourseId implements java.io.Serializable {


    @ManyToOne
    private Student student;
    @ManyToOne
    private Course course;

    public Student getStudent() {
        return student;
    }
    public void setStudent(Student student) {
        this.student = student;
    }
    public Course getCourse() {
        return course;
    }
    public void setCourse(Course course) {
        this.course = course;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        StudentCourseId that = (StudentCourseId) o;

        if (student != null ? !student.equals(that.student) : that.student != null) return false;
        if (course != null ? !course.equals(that.course) : that.course != null)
            return false;

        return true;
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        int result;
        result = (student != null ? student.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (course != null ? course.hashCode() : 0);
        return result;
    }
}
```

***Service***

```
//find a student by its ID
public Optional<Student> getStudentById(Long studentID) throws SQLException{

    return studentRepo.findById(studentID);
}
```

***Controller***

```
//find a student by its ID
@GetMapping("/findStudent/{studentID}")
public ResponseEntity<?> getStudentById(@PathVariable Long studentID){      

    student = sts.getStudentById(studentID).orElse(new Student());
    return new ResponseEntity<>(student, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

***Json response***

[image]

de baixo de "studentCourses" eu gostaria de ter a lista de cursos que o estudante se cadastrou, mas está me retornando uma recursão infinita do próprio estudante...

Obrigado desde já.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está tendo recursão infinita porque o jackson não está sabendo onde parar de serializar seu objeto, sem ver toda a stacktrace, suspeito que seja na hora que ele esteja escrevendo o StudentCourseId.

Quando ele começa a escrever Student e chega na propriedade studentCourses e tenta escrever o pk do tipo StudentCourseId, observe que você tem uma referência para Student novamente.

Tente usar a anotação @JsonIgnoreProperties em cima do atributo student de StudentCourseId (repita no course se necessário).

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;

...

@ManyToOne
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"studentCourses"})
private Student student;

@ManyToOne
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"studentCourses"})
private Course course;
```

Comment: realmente, era um problema no parsing do jackson, deu para solucionar com ```@JsonIgnoreProperties``` e também funcionou anotando a nível de classe com ```@JsonIdentityInfo``` . Muito Obrigado!